# Getting an error "str.substr is not a function" when use my browser for the localhost page but server is running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am getting the following error when request my webpage after starting the server (the server runs properly, the problem occurs when I request the page):

```
TypeError: str.substr is not a function at createGetter (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\method-override\index.js:88:11)
at methodOverride (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\method-override\index.js:50:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at logger (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\morgan\index.js:144:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mypath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
```

I am still learning about the MEAN stack, please bear with me, my server.js is as follows:

```
var express = require('express'),
favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
stylus = require('stylus'),
logger = require('morgan'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
session = require('express-session'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
multer = require('multer'),
upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/'}),
errorHandler = require('errorhandler');

var app = express();

function compile(src, path) {
return stylus(src).set('filename', path);
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(methodOverride);
app.use(session(
    {resave: true, saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'uwotm8'}
));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

//app.use(multer());
app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
        src: __dirname + '/public',
        compile: compile
    }
));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
```

I installed all dependencies used in the server.js file (I read from a post that this was the new way of doing it as opposed to var express only as in my tutorials), I also commented out multer because I'm not sure how to use it (if I uncomment it I get an error when I run nodemon server.js), I am watching old tutorials as I have no access to modern ones at the moment, any help will be graciously appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`app.use(methodOverride);` should be something like `app.use(methodOverride('_method'));`, depending on your setup. See the [examples](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#examples) for more ideas/information.

Also, the problem you're having with `multer` is most likely because you're trying to use the old API, but the API changed some time ago (see the example [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage)).

Answer (score 3):

replace `app.use(methodOverride);` with `app.use(methodOverride());`